# hide Navbar to work in interfice builder iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, hide, navbar

I'm building a view in my iOS app with Xcode.
I'm using the interfice builder and because it's a navigation controller, the navigation bar appears.
With code, I hide the navigation bar using:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

It works ok, but in interfice builder it keeps showing. How can I hide it in interfice builder to draw my view easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the inspector on IB, there is a navigation bar dropdown. You should be able to simply change that to none, and it will go away from your view in IB.